# how to read/write data with UnSafeRawPointer in BlueSocket?

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, networking

**Text is being transferred in the form of string using that library but i want to send big file using this pre-defined methods of BlueSocket library**

> `write(from buffer: UnsafeRawPointer, bufSize: Int)`

i don't have any clue how to use it

Github link of library: https://github.com/IBM-Swift/BlueSocket

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Can't you use the 'write(data:)' overload? It should be much simpler

Comment: Write data has the limit (like max buffer size in BlueSocket is 1448)
i want to send file like 10 to 20 MB using that write method
can you elaborate more? @Losiowaty